# angular material disable controls using fieldset

Tags: angular, angular-material, disabled-control

I am using `angular material 7.2.0`.
I am trying to disable form fields using `fieldset` container.
for input controls it works, but not for `mat-select`.
I know I can declare it in both fieldset and mat-select and it works but I want more generic code to affect this.

sample of my code:

```
<fieldset disabled="true">
    <form>
      <div>
          <label>סיבת הבדיקה</label>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select>
              <mat-option [value]="undefined||null"></mat-option>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let reason of reasons"
                          [value]="reason.Code"
                          [matTooltip]="reason.Desc">
                {{reason.Desc}}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error>
              חובה להזין ערך בשדה
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>הערות</label>
            <mat-form-field>
              <textarea maxlength="1200"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>מבצע</label>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput
                     maxlength="100" />
              <mat-error>
                חובה להזין ערך בשדה
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS pointer-events property

> The pointer-events CSS property sets under what circumstances (if any)
>   a particular graphic element can become the target of pointer events.

```
<fieldset [ngStyle]="{'pointer-events':true ? 'none' : 'none' }" >
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select">
      <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</fieldset>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ympzvr

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem is that the user can get the control focused using tab control and with keyboard can change the controls value.
any other idea?

Comment: for mat-select it is work but for my custom input control it does not work.

Comment: for your custom input control Which one are using div or input element?

Comment: it does not help me because I want to apply the disable attribute to all controls in fieldset and tabindex I need to declare in each control

Comment: Do not use pointer-events for this, it is not the same as disabling. It won't disable keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing the fieldset and setting the form to disable using ngAfterContentChecked event in ts file.

see attached link how to use it.

[disable form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159276/angular-6-formgroup-disable-method-is-not-working-with-my-template-driven-ngfo/51161034#51161034)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use fieldset [disabled] to disable angular controls.** Although the controls will have a visual of a disabled controls, **if there's a validation on them it will still be triggered**.

You should always **disable the controls and/or a control group** - as they have the corresponding angular object behind them, disabling the control group will propagate the state down to the nested angular controls.

**There's also a possibility to write a custom directive you can attach on any HTML element**, to which every inner angular control will be registered and thus the directive could disable all those controls properly:

```
<fieldset [groupDisabled]="isDisabled">
   ...
</fieldset>
```

The code for that directive can be found here: https://gist.github.com/hidegh/f7ce58156ecc2bb4351f24b3742ed52d